# Product image field best practice

Tags: commerce

I am building a site selling engineering components. There are many Variations of some of the products but each variant looks almost identical.

Would I be better placed having an image field for each variant or just one image field in the product type?
If I go down the 'image field in the variant' option, then each variant would have the exact same image; yet, this doesn't strike me as sensible.

Answer (score 0):

If the image doesn't really vary by variation, I would put it on the product. This will save you disk space / database space in the long run. Alternately, you may be able to use the Media module to upload the image once and reference it from all of the variations. This would let you use a single product type to handle product pages whether their variations required different images or not.

At the end of the day, there is no single best option here.

Comment: Ok, thanks Ryan, I'll put it in the product. Regards.